# Building a zoom-able / pan-able container

Tags: android, zooming, viewgroup, android-framelayout, panning

I am trying to make a ViewGroup which supports panning and zooming of its contents. All I could find online was ideas and implementations to do so in an ImageView, but never a container. I want to display a map, and on top of it I want to display multiple markers which are ImageButtons, so the user may tap them to get more information. This is achieved on iOS by means of the UIScrollView, but I could not find an alternative on Android.

I decided to use a FrameView, so I could set an ImageView with the image as background, and on top of it add a RelativeLayout, on which I could add the ImageButtons and position them using margins.

I borrowed part of the implementation of the TouchImageView [here](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView), but I've ran into complications. I've started with panning, and I partially succeeded, it pans the container around, but the panning works hideously, it jitters a lot. Here's my code:

```
public class ScrollingViewGroup extends FrameLayout {

    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 0;

    // We can be in one of these 3 states
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;

    // Remember some things for zooming
    PointF last = new PointF();
    PointF start = new PointF();

public ScrollingViewGroup(Context context) {
        super(context);
        sharedConstructing(context);
    }

    public ScrollingViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        sharedConstructing(context);
    }

    private void sharedConstructing(Context context) {
        super.setClickable(true);
        this.context = context;
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());

    setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

                PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    last.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                    start.set(last);
                    mode = DRAG;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (mode == DRAG) {
                        float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                        float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                        Log.d("ScrollingViewGroup", Float.toString(deltaX));
                        Log.d("ScrollingViewGroup", Float.toString(deltaY));
                        float scaleWidth = Math.round(origWidth * saveScale);
                        float scaleHeight = Math.round(origHeight * saveScale);


                        x += deltaX;
                        y += deltaY;



                        last.set(curr.x, curr.y);

                    }
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    mode = NONE;
                    int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                    int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                    if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                        performClick();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    mode = NONE;
                    break;
                }
                // setImageMatrix(matrix);
                setTranslationX(x);
                setTranslationY(y);
                invalidate();
                return true; // indicate event was handled
            }

        });
    }
```

Any ideas are very appreciated.

edit: jitter seems to be cause because when moving, deltaX and deltaY alternate between positive and negative numbers, checking LogCat... still not sure why.
This is caused by the curr variable which gives different values each time, but instead of being consistent, they seem as if the finger would be moving back and forth instead of just forwards. For example, instead of curr.x being 0,1,2,3,4,etc, it is 0,1,0.5,2,1.5, etc.. Not sure why either.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am looking for the exact same thing. A zoom/pan able map with buttons

Comment: Hey, sorry, I left the company a while back and I'm unable to provide code, I did find some workaround, but cannot possibly recall how I did it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that works with some prerequisites:

- the items in the container need to be of type ImageView
- All images need to be of the same size in order to zoom equally

The items in the container can be zoomed and panned (but not at the same time). The code is also able to figure out if a user has clicked instead of moving or zooming.
The ImageViews are stored in an ArrayList in a FrameLayout and are scaled and moved together. Some parts of this code are taken from a very nice article on ZDNet by Ed Burnette ([Link](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2/1747)), which is taken from the really good Android book "[Hello, Android](http://pragprog.com/book/eband3/hello-android)".

Check out this code. You can use this class as layout in any activity. You should even be able to use it in the XML. For now there is a method initializeViews() that is called in the constructor where you can hard code the imageviews that should be loaded when the layout is created. You should add some bitmaps in this method after the line "ArrayList sampleBitmaps = new ArrayList();"
For real use it's probably better to implement a method addImageView(ImageView item) where you can add views dynamically.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.FloatMath;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType;


public class TouchContainer extends FrameLayout implements OnTouchListener {

    // constants
    private static final Config DEFAULT_COLOR_DEPTH = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444;
    private static final String TAG = "TouchContainer";

    // fields
    private ArrayList<ImageView> items;

    public TouchContainer(Context ctx) {
        this(ctx, null);
    }

    public TouchContainer(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(ctx, attrs);

        initializeViews();  // initialize some sample Bitmaps
    }

    /**
     * This method is just to make an example 
     */
    protected void initializeViews() {
        ScaleType scaleType = ScaleType.MATRIX;

        // array needs to be created here if used in XML
        items = new ArrayList<ImageView>();


        ArrayList<Bitmap> sampleBitmaps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
        // here you should add some bitmaps to the Array that will then be displayed in the container
        // e.g. sampleBitmaps.add(blabla I'm a bitmap) :-)

        ImageView iv = null;
        boolean firstLoop = true;

        for (Bitmap bitmap : sampleBitmaps) {
            // Load the bitmaps into imageviews
            iv = new ImageView(getContext());
            iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            iv.setScaleType(scaleType);
            if (firstLoop) {
                // add the touch listener to the first image view that is stored in the ArrayList
                iv.setOnTouchListener(this);
                firstLoop = false;
            }

            // add view to the FrameLayout
            this.addView(iv);

            // add the imageview to the array
            items.add(iv);
        }

    }



    protected void transformImages(Matrix matrix) {
        for (ImageView image : items) {
            image.setImageMatrix(matrix);
        }

    }




    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

    // states
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;
    static final int CLICK = 3;


    PointF start = new PointF();
    PointF mid = new PointF();
    float oldDist = 1f;

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


      switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
         savedMatrix.set(matrix);
         start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
         Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG");
         mode = DRAG;
         break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
         oldDist = spacing(event);
         Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
         if (oldDist > 10f) {
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            midPoint(mid, event);
            mode = ZOOM;
            Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
         }
         break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
          // figure out if user clicked
          mode = NONE;
          int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(event.getX() - start.x);
          int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(event.getY() - start.y);
          if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
              performClick(); 
          break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
         mode = NONE;
         Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
         break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
         if (mode == DRAG) {

            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
            matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x,
                  event.getY() - start.y);
         }
         else if (mode == ZOOM) {
            float newDist = spacing(event);
            Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
            if (newDist > 10f) {
               matrix.set(savedMatrix);
               float scale = newDist / oldDist;
               matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
            }
         }
         break;
      }


      transformImages(matrix);


      return true;
   }




       private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
          float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
          float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
          return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
       }


       private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
          float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
          float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
          point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
       }





}
```